# Dynamic bash alias based on the location

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following folder structure:

```
  alpha
    src
       doit.py
   beta
    src
       doit.py
   gama
    src
       doit.py
```

and the command

```
python ../../doit.py --clean --add_source inner
```

I want to create an alias, `doit` that executes the corresponding file depending in which parent folder I'm located.

For example:

1. If I'm inside `alpha` or one of is sub-directories, when I use:

   `doit --addsource  extra`

to actually run:

`python /home/alpha/src/doit.py --clean --addsource  extra`

2. If I'm inside `beta` or one of is sub-directories, when I use:

   `doit --addsource  inner`

to actually run:

```
python /home/beta/src/doit.py --clean --addsource  inner
```

Comment: This feature (directory specific local aliases) has originally been invented in 1980 on UNOS, the first UNIX clone. Since 8 years, it is available in the maintained version of the Bourne Shell - see schilytools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be better served by a shell function:

```
doit () {
    local dir

    case $PWD/ in
        /home/alpha/*) dir=alpha ;;
        /home/beta/*)  dir=beta  ;;
        /home/gamma/*) dir=gamma ;;
        *) echo 'Not standing in the correct directory' >&2
           return 1
    esac

    python "/home/$dir/src/doit.py" --clean "$@"
}
```

This would set the variable `dir` to the string `alpha`, `beta` or `gamma` depending on the current working directory, or complain that you're in the wrong directory tree if the current directory is elsewhere.

It then runs the Python script, utilizing the `$dir` value, with the `--clean` option and adds whatever other arguments that you've passed to the function.

You would add this shell function's definition to wherever you ordinarily add aliases.

Comment: I wonder if there's an argument to make for returning 127 from the case statement, to help distinguish between a failure to run the script and a failure of the script itself.

Comment: @chepner There's an argument for that, but rather than failing to execute a command, we're detecting that the user is located in a invalid directory. I dunno, it's probably not too important.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use it like below:

```
alias doit='doit=$(pwd)/src/doit.py;$doit --clean'
```